# Using of "therefore" in one sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation

I've heard "therefore" is used at the beginning of sentence. I used it in a depending sentence.

> However, there are other works that claim the HTML is mainly used for the presentation **layer; therefore, t**he DOM tree is not reliable to discriminate different semantic portions of a web page.

Did I do it correctly?

Do I need other words like "thus" or "hence" for this sentence and position?

Comment: You have used therefore correctly. Alternatively, you can start the sentence with therefore (Therefore, .....). The use of thus or since in addition to therefore will make the sentence unidiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used a semi-colon, both clauses are independent, meaning that they could stand alone as sentences.
Therefore, you did not really change the "starting a sentence" rule with *; therefore*.

Your example as written is OK. You should be careful about overusing intro. words (however, therefore in your example). Consider the necessity for using them.

Answer (score 2):

"Only use 'therefore' at the beginning of a sentence" is not a valid rule.

Perhaps you could say that "therefore" should only be used at the beginning of a CLAUSE.

> I think, therefore I am.

Your example is also perfectly valid.

Comment: Another example of "therefore" within a sentence would be something like "The dog, therefore, carried his bone out into the back yard and proceeded to bury it."

Comment: @imkingdavid Yes. So even a rule that it must begin a clause is not valid.